# T1 fontenc with utf8 inputenc don't behave well together in the output pdf

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, output, coding

if I use the following document

```
 \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \begin{document}
 Why is this output so strange öäü at zoom 100\\
 \end{document}
```

then there is some strange behaviour in the output document. Take a look yourself:
[image]

Can someone explain this?? If I don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, this problem does not appear in the pdf-document. But I would like to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for the more aesthetic output regarding ö,ä,ü,ß,Ö,Ä,Ü,...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did not immediately see the problem, you might want to clarify and add higher maginifications. I think, it's a problem of the hinting / rasterization in your PDF viewer. Try using zoom level 400% and more or printing. It should look Ok in print.

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I mean if I let out the [T1]{fontenc} then there is no problem at any zoomscale...

Comment: Which latex system are you using?

Comment: I use TexMaker with MikTex.

Comment: Then my guess is that you are using bitmap computer modern as that is the debault in miktex (for some reason). What are the changes if you add `\usepackage{lmodern}`? I tend to use TeXLive and there the default font is CM-super which is *not* bit map.

Comment: Hey daleif, if I use your usepackage, there is no problem anymore. Could you pleae write a whole answer that describes this behaviour?

Comment: Alternatively install the cm-super package with the MiKTeX console.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do I have to include in my document by \usepackage{...} or is it only necessary to download this package from CTAN?

Comment: You don't need any package but use the MiKTeX console to install - cm-super contains  many font files and the console knows where they belong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can't find my MikTex console. Is it even installed? I already looked at some threads with this problem, but did not find any solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using MikTeX my guess is that your default font is a bitmap version of Computer Modern. I use TeXLive where the so-called CM-super font is the default. This is a vector version of Computer Modern. Bitmap are not scalable and may appear grainy when zoomed in.

A recommended solution (as Ulrike pointed out): install the `cm-super` package (it is a bit large).

Alternatively switch to the Latin Modern font, aka `\usepackage{lmodern}`, which is also a vector font.

Comment: Now I have another problem with this: I switched to Tex Live and have installed cm-super. But the problem is not solved! So installing cm-super had no effects. 
If I use \usepackage{lmodern} my ,,W''s are bold. See my new thread here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549406/lmodern-and-t1fontenc-strange-pdf-output?noredirect=1#comment1388596_549406