# lmodern and T1fontenc strange pdf output

Tags: pdf, bold, lmodern, pixelated

first of all: I use TexMaker and installed the full TexLive datas. My pdf-document program is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
If I use `\usepackages{lmodern}`, then the W's in my pdf-document in Adobe Acrobat Reader are bold, but not in the TexMaker pdf next to the source code.
If I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the adobe acrobat pdf-document is pixelated.

Changing the rendering properties of Adobe Acrobat does not have any effect...
Can someone explain this behaviour?
My template:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\noindent
We will Wuse Wlots wof W's win wthis Wdocument! \\
Änd Here äre söme ümläüuts. \\
Dony't forgeyt thye y's righty herey! \\
\end{document}
```

Output in adobe acrobat pdf at zoom 125%:

(1) without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and without `\usepackage{lmodern}`
Looks perfect (but umlauts good look better).

(2) with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and without `\usepackage{lmodern}`
t is pixelated (in another document y as well).

(3) without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and with `\usepackage{lmodern}`
W's are bold. We can not see it very well, but trust me, the W's are fatttt :D

(4) with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and with `\usepackage{lmodern}`
W's are bold.

[image]

Log-File:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.6.16)  16 JUN 2020 23:26
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**asdf.tex
(./asdf.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-03>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/06/10 3.45 The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/06/10 3.45 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count175
\U@D=\dimen135
\l@babelnohyphens=\language86

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count176

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language21) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language21) on input line 108.
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version` normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version` bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count177
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(./asdf.aux)
\openout1 = `asdf.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 6.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--12

[]

[1

{c:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./asdf.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1332 strings out of 480478
18665 string characters out of 5903485
263655 words of memory out of 5000000
17412 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
536091 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
25i,4n,24p,159b,108s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{
c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-
dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>
Output written on asdf.pdf (1 page, 28715 bytes).
PDF statistics:
13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Here again a pic at zoom 50%.
First line uses `\textbf{W}`. Second line not.
[image]

Comment: "pixelated" probably means that you should install the cm-super package. But for the bold W you should show a minimal example (and first check if it is not a viewer problem and the zoom level).

Comment: Hey, since I've downloaded the whole texlive, cm-super should be installed. 
If I don't use either of the above usepackages, everything is fine (just the umlauts ä,ö,ü are not so ''nice''...) There are W's which will remain bold at each zoom level and W's which change to be bold at a certain zoom level. :S

Comment: You should always use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` if your text contains umlauts. If this give pixelated output show a small complete example of your code and the log-file.

Comment: I would personally recommend that you use modern fonts when you can and 8-bit technology from last century when you have to. However, that shouldn’t be happening if you have a complete, correct installation. It’s a big download, but you might want to clean your TeX installation out and do a fresh install. Or, if your OS package manager supports it, install that way. Also check that you don’t have two copies of it clashing?

Comment: Hey Davislor, I installed everything two days ago. I think everything should be nice. Above you can see an example of the output.

Comment: I said: show the log-file of the pixelated version. Screenshots don't allow to see which fonts are used. But beside this: the W are not bold in your screenshot. Compare with \textbf{W}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The W's are bold even if I don't use \textbf{...}.
I hope the log.file above is fine? I don't know how to put it in a clear code :S
Btw above is no the logfile of the pixelated version, it is the logfile of the bold W's.

Comment: Your W are not bold, compare with a really bold W:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id9im.png

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Take a look at my new edit. There is a new screenshot of my output...

Comment: Can we please have the log for the image without lmodern. If possible I'd also like to see the PDF that you say becomes bold in Acrobat DC, I'd like to test that on a different PC.